# How to change the style of a widget during runtime Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, checkbox, styles, runtime

I am working on a project where it is necessary to change a checkbox's style dynamically during runtime, I have gone through many other options listed on the sight but, most of them require creating a new instance of the object which isn't possible in my case, any insight to this dilemma would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the checkbox object during runtime you can edit it dynamically. For example you can check it with

`myCheckBox.setChecked(true);`

You can change the coloring like this if you are in the same context:

> for android<23

```
int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
int colors[] = {ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myCheckedCheckboxColor),ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myUncheckedCheckboxColor)};
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(myCheckBox,new ColorStateList(states,colors));
```

> for android>=23

```
int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
int colors[] = {ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myCheckedCheckboxColor),ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myUncheckedCheckboxColor)};
myCheckBox.setForegroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states,colors)); // <-- requires @TargetApi(23)
CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(myCheckBox,new ColorStateList(states,colors));
```

You can edit other style attributes like this as well. 
I don't know if you need to set all attributes yourself or if you can just apply the new style as a simple oneliner though...

**Update:**

Implement it somewhat like this:
Go into /res/values/ folder and add two new colors in colors.xml
`myCheckedCheckboxColor`
`myUncheckedCheckboxColor`
(or programm a new Color element during runtime)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity ... {

    Context ctx = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ctx = MainActivity.this;

        ...
    }

    protected void changeColorOfCheckBox(CheckBox myCheckBox){
        int osVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(osVersion>=23){
            changeColorOfCheckBox23(myCheckBox);
        }
        else{
            int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
            int colors[] = {ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myCheckedCheckboxColor),ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myUncheckedCheckboxColor)};
            CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(myCheckBox,new ColorStateList(states,colors));
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    protected void changeColorOfCheckBox23(CheckBox myCheckBox){
        int states[][] = {{android.R.attr.state_checked}, {}};
        int colors[] = {ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myCheckedCheckboxColor),ctx.getResources().getColor(R.color.myUncheckedCheckboxColor)};
        myCheckBox.setForegroundTintList(new ColorStateList(states,colors)); // <-- requires @TargetApi(23)
        CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(myCheckBox,new ColorStateList(states,colors));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is my first actual project using Android Studio, so I am unfamiliar with what the cxt references.

Comment: I tried my best to implement this and when the code is ran it crashes the app.

Comment: Hi @ZmanBman Bman you can use ```this``` or ```MainActivity.this``` since it refers to a ```Context``` which is always on your active activity classes 

(not all subclasses though, it is recommended to store Context ctx = MainActivity.this if you need it in a helper-class somewhere else, also if you change to another active activity or service use only the active context)

Comment: i updated the answer, please mark your problem as solved if it helped :)